# Implementing Quantum Addition in C# for Solving Complex Problems

Tags: c#, quantum-computing

```
var simulator = new QuantumSimulator();
int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
QArray<int> qNumbers = new QArray<int>(numbers);
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < qNumbers.Length; i++) {
    var register = new QArray<int>(new int[] { qNumbers[i], sum });
    simulator.OnRun += () => Microsoft.Quantum.Primitive.Swap.Run(simulator, register[0], register[1]);
    simulator.Run(new Microsoft.Quantum.Samples.QSharp.Swap());
    sum = register[0];
}
Console.WriteLine("The sum is " + sum);
```

The above code attempts to use a quantum computing simulator to calculate the sum of an array of integers. But it doesn't work !!!
Error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The sum calculated by the quantum algorithm is incorrect.
   at MyProgram.Main() in C:\MyProgram.cs:line 17
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The sum calculated by the quantum algorithm is incorrect.
   at MyProgram.Main() in C:\MyProgram.cs:line 17

Comment: Is this some async / callback event based api? You probably want to wait for each execution to finish before starting another. I doubt you really want to register so many `OnRun` event handlers to the same `QuantumSimulator` instance.

Comment: I found other solution:  to calculate the sum of an array of integers using a quantum algorithm, you can use the quantum Fourier transform algorithm. Here is an example code that demonstrates how to do this using Q# and C#.